# How to wait for a task to complete before executing next task for a Cloud Run Job?

Tags: bash, shell, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I'm building an execution flow for running certain tasks as a Cloud Run Job, first one should be completed before running the next.
I was trying to follow the given sample shell script code, but it seems we can achieve parallelism, but all the tasks will be executed simultaneously. Still, in my scenario, I want to wait till my first task is completed, and based on the execution status whether Failed or Success, the next set of tasks should be executed in parallel. Any recommendations or workaround over here?

Below is the sample shell script taken from the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/jobs/build-create-shell) page-

```
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

# In production, consider printing commands as they are executed. 
# This helps with debugging if things go wrong and you only 
# have the logs.
#
# Add -x:
# `set -euox pipefail`

CLOUD_RUN_TASK_INDEX=${CLOUD_RUN_TASK_INDEX:=0}
CLOUD_RUN_TASK_ATTEMPT=${CLOUD_RUN_TASK_ATTEMPT:=0}

echo "Starting Task #${CLOUD_RUN_TASK_INDEX}, Attempt #${CLOUD_RUN_TASK_ATTEMPT}..."

# SLEEP_MS and FAIL_RATE should be a decimal
# numbers. parse and format the input using 
# printf. 
#
# printf validates the input since it 
# quits on invalid input, as shown here:
#
#   $: printf '%.1f' "abc"
#   bash: printf: abc: invalid number
#
SLEEP_MS=$(printf '%.1f' "${SLEEP_MS:=0}")
FAIL_RATE=$(printf '%.1f' "${FAIL_RATE:=0}")

# Wait for a specific amount of time to simulate
# performing some work
SLEEP_SEC=$(echo print\("${SLEEP_MS}"/1000\) | perl)
sleep "$SLEEP_SEC" # sleep accepts seconds, not milliseconds

# Fail the task with a likelihood of $FAIL_RATE

# Bash does not do floating point arithmetic. Use perl 
# to convert into integer and multiply by 100.
FAIL_RATE_INT=$(echo print\("int(${FAIL_RATE:=0}*100"\)\) | perl)

# Generate a random number between 0 and 100
RAND=$(( RANDOM % 100))
if (( RAND < FAIL_RATE_INT )); then 
    echo "Task #${CLOUD_RUN_TASK_INDEX}, Attempt #${CLOUD_RUN_TASK_ATTEMPT} failed."
    exit 1
else 
    echo "Completed Task #${CLOUD_RUN_TASK_INDEX}."
fi
```

Answer (score 3):

In your case (IMO), if you want to wait for a task with a `Cloud Run` job to execute another, the best and simpler solution is to use `Cloud Workflows`.

`Workflows` is a serverless tool that allows to apply orchestration between tasks on GCP services.
It's based on API calls and a YAML file.

You can check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/tutorials/execute-cloud-run-jobs#deploy-workflow) that shows an example :

```yaml
main:
    params: [event]
    steps:
        - init:
            assign:
                - project_id: ${sys.get_env("GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID")}
                - event_bucket: ${event.data.bucket}
                - event_file: ${event.data.name}
                - target_bucket: ${"input-" + project_id}
                - job_name: parallel-job
                - job_location: us-central1
        - check_input_file:
            switch:
                - condition: ${event_bucket == target_bucket}
                  next: run_job
                - condition: true
                  next: end
        - run_job:
            call: googleapis.run.v1.namespaces.jobs.run
            args:
                name: ${"namespaces/" + project_id + "/jobs/" + job_name}
                location: ${job_location}
                body:
                    overrides:
                        containerOverrides:
                            env:
                                - name: INPUT_BUCKET
                                  value: ${event_bucket}
                                - name: INPUT_FILE
                                  value: ${event_file}
            result: job_execution
        - finish:
            return: ${job_execution}
```

You can trigger a `Cloud Run` job with the [Cloud Run Admin API Connector](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/googleapis/run/Overview). By using `googleapis.run.v1.namespaces.jobs.run`, it waits until the operation is complete, fails, or times out.

You can then execute the second job in the following task in `Workflows`.

Comment: I recommend using this solution as well.

Comment: Good answer Mazlum. Task in Cloud Run Jobs are by design parallelized to speed up the job processing (by splitting the large process in smaller chunks). If you want orchestration, use an orchestrator.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve by keeping method.

So it will be in sequence.

```
cloud_run_index{
CLOUD_RUN_TASK_INDEX=${CLOUD_RUN_TASK_INDEX:=0}
}
cloud_run_attempt{
CLOUD_RUN_TASK_ATTEMPT=${CLOUD_RUN_TASK_ATTEMPT:=0
echo "Starting Task #${CLOUD_RUN_TASK_INDEX}, Attempt #${CLOUD_RUN_TASK_ATTEMPT}..."
}

cloud_run_index
cloud_run_attempt
```

Comment: Can you explain it a bit more with some example?

Comment: It will not got to next step until complete a step inside method.